# Discord.JS Invalid Form Body in command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When im starting my discord bot on discord.js v 14.7.1 this error shows up, and I don't know how can I fix it

```
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
 rawError: {
    errors: { '0': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
    errors: { '0': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
```

In error there's two objects, but I don't have any other file in commands folder
Here's the only one command that I have in files. in directory commands/tools/embed.js.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("embed")
        .setDescription("Embeds a message"),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Embed Title")
            .setDescription("Embed Description")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp(Date.now())
            .setFooter({
                iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
                text: client.user.tag
            })
            .addFields([
                {
                    name: 'Field 1',
                    value: 'Filed value 1',
                    inline: true
                }
            ])
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
}
```

and heres my commands handler

```
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async () => {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands');
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

            const {commands, commandArray } = client;
            for (const file of commandFiles){
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                commands.set(command.data.name, command)
                commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
                console.log(`Loaded command ${command.data.name}`);
            }
        }
        const clientId = '1040763751864995971';
        const guildId = '1000901014158856272'

        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
            await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: client.commandArray });
            console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: I didn't try anything, i just don't know what is causing the problem. Console.log of commandArray shows me this]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

When I was pushing the command to the commandArray, I was pushing the Command object too. The array I needed to send to the API is only a string array, so...

replace this

```
   for (const file of commandFiles){
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                commands.set(command.data.name, command)
                commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
                console.log(`Loaded command ${command.data.name}`);
            }
```

with this

```
 for (const file of commandFiles){
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                commands.set(command.data.name, command)
                commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
                console.log(`Loaded command ${command.data.name}`);
            }
```